# C++ polymorphism with boost scoped_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, polymorphism, scoped-ptr

Why does the following code not allow foo(ptr) to be called ?

```
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
struct A {
    virtual ~A() {}
};

struct B: public A {};

void foo(boost::scoped_ptr<A>& a) {}

void goo(A& a) {}
int main() {
    boost::scoped_ptr<B> ptr(new B);
    foo(ptr);
    B b;
    goo(b);
}
```

The corresponding form where we pass references works as expected. Are we supposed not to do polymorphism
with boost scoped_ptr ?

g++ with boost 1.49 gives me:

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘boost::scoped_ptr<A>&’ from expression of type ‘boost::scoped_ptr<B>’
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `foo`, for some reason, takes a scoped pointer *by reference*. That is completely unnecessary and is the reason why the call fails. There is a conversion from `scoped_ptr<B>` to `scoped_ptr<A>` but not from `scoped_ptr<B>&` to `scoped_ptr<A>&`.

You should pass it as reference to const.

```
void foo(boost::scoped_ptr<A> const & a) {}
```

Incidentally, this isn't a "problem" of smart pointers per se. The following code fails for the same reasons as yours.

```
void foo(A*& p) {}
int main()
{
    B* p = new B;
    foo(p); //FAIL
}
```

In order to fix this you have to pass the pointer either by value, or, if you're sufficiently perverted, by reference to const

```
 void foo (A * const & p); // <-- a perv wrote this
```

Comment: wouldn't that need a copy of scoped_ptrs, which has a private copy constructor ? In any case, I want the scoped_ptr to persist  in the callee.

Comment: changing foo() to make scoped_ptr instead of reference gives me: error: conversion from ‘boost::scoped_ptr<B>’ to non-scalar type ‘boost::scoped_ptr<A>’ requested

Comment: If you want it to persist in the callee then I'm pretty sure you don't want a `scoped_ptr`. You want `unique_ptr` if you're transferring ownership or `shared_ptr` if both places retain pointership to it.

Comment: @Armen: I am puzzled - why does the const reference work and const does not ?

Comment: @MMarkb: Perhaps ptr is a member variable in a class. We can pass the member variable in a method by reference but want the variable to be cleaned up when the object is destroyed not when the called function exists. Am I thinking incorrectly here?

Comment: @ATemp: Because in order to pass something by reference, the types must match exactly. But if it's reference to const, then conversions can take place. C++ rules

Comment: @ATemp, think of it this way; what happens if you assign an `A *` to something which appears as a `B *` in the caller scope. By saying it's `const` you're promising not to do that.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: what if I want to mutate ptr in foo() ? For example, by doing a ptr.reset(new A). Passing const reference will not let me do that. Specifically, I want foo to treat ptr as non-const and still allow polymorphic arguments. Is that possible?

Comment: @Atemp: In that case foo must take scoped_ptr<B>&, not A