# C++ Rules for argument substitution

Tags: c++, templates, arguments, template-argument-deduction

Following [C++ polymorphism with boost scoped_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845584/c-polymorphism-with-boost-scoped-ptr),
I would like to understand the rules of C++ argument deduction. For example:

1. the rules for C++ polymorphic substitutions, when smart pointers and
   containers are used
2. automatic conversions, between const and non-const arguments
3. when can temporaries be passed as references?
4. how do the rules differ in template argument deduction.

If there is a relevant section in the standard you can point to that would help too.

Comment: Very good question, but it's very broad. Might want to break it down into multiple questions.

Comment: OK. Is it better to have this as a community wiki? I will refactor.

Comment: What exactly are you unsure about? At which point was your textbook unclear?

Comment: In the question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845584/c-polymorphism-with-boost-scoped-ptr, the polymorphic substitution for const reference but not for non-const reference surprised me.

Comment: @ATemp: That question doesn't really have anything to do with polymorphism, but rather with temporaries binding to const-references. As with most of your question, you're touching on a million little parts of C++ which are probably best mastered by learning the language more rather than asking for a be-all-end-all recipe.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is far too broad and I don't understand what all the questions are. Jere is my shot:

1. Template deduction doesn't care about base classes or conversions. It deduces a static type. Only if there is no direct match it will try if a conversion can solve this and as usual it will only apply one conversion. For example it the type passed is a raw pointer and the expected type is a smart pointer which can be implicitly converted from a build-in pointer it should find this.
2. For value types constness is ignored. For reference or pointer types a non-const pointer or reference can convert to the corresponding non-const version. The deduced tupe won't have cv-qualifiers, however, although it can be possible to instantiate the same function explicitly with cv-qualifird types. It you deduce ab`T&&` different rules apply.
3. Temporary can only bind to `const` qualified lvalue references and to rvalue references. This is universal in the language.
4. What is this comparison against?